# Hide form without a fading effect in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, show-hide, fadeout

I am using 2 forms in my project. I want to hide the main form and open the second when a button is clicked.

NOTE: Both forms look exactly the same

I use this code, and it works fine:

```
Me.Hide()
Form2.Show()
```

The only problem is that there is a closing / fading effect when the main form is being hidden... However I want it to be instant (So users shouldn't notice that anything happened)

Is this possible? If so, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this...

Comment: Why hide it anyways? I am curious...I see you are using default form instance names give them a constructive name. It also tells me your probably not instantiating the forms rather using default instances. Also your using `Show` if you use `ShowDialog` a user can't interact with other forms until that one is closed...

Comment: What you're suggesting may not be possible and, if it is, may be fiddly to accomplish because that's the OS providing that effect.  If you don't want it to appear to the user that the form has changed then maybe just don;t change the form.  You can use multiple `Panels` or user controls in the same form to show a different set of functionality at different times, like a `TabControl` with no tabs.  I'd suggest that should be the way you go, if indeed you actually do need to hide the first form at all.

Comment: I just re-read your post and I see that both forms actually look the same.  Why use two of them at all in that case?  Presumably you have a reason but it may not really be justified.

Comment: Use `Me.visible = False` instead of `.Hide`

Comment: @MattWilko can you please explain why to use the `visible` property instead?

Comment: @Zaggler Don't worry I don't use default things, it was just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the form opacity to 0 then show form2

```
Me.Opacity = 0
Form2.Show()
Me.Hide()
Me.Opacity = 100
```

Then set opacity to 100 after your main form has been hidden

Comment: Okay thanks, that's pretty easy, don't know why I didn't think of this...

Answer (score 1):

You could possible improve the effect by showing `Form2` first and then after a very slight pause hide `Form1`.

```
Form2.Show()
Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Hide()
```

Doesn't quite achieve the instantaneous effect but as `Form1` is now in the background it isn't quite so noticeable.